# Optimising Eager Load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, arel

I have a `Gallery` that `has_many` `MediaItem`s, each of which `has_one` `Video` or `Photo`.

I'm currently using the following query:

```
MediaItem.includes(gallery: {media_items: [:photo, :video]}).featured.rank(:position_in_featured)
```

However given that the media item will only ever have a `Video` or a `Photo`, I am always left with an unused eager load for whichever it doesn't have.

Is there a more efficient way of querying to avoid this unneeded include?

*Note: I don't need a solution that involves Polymorphic associations. In this case they introduce too much complexity to other queries and don't fit the data model.*

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would probably be changing your data model to a [polymorphic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) relationship and using a `belongs_to` association in `MediaItem`

```
class MediaItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :media_content, :polymorphic => true
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :media_items, :as => :media_content
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :media_items, :as => :media_content
end

MediaItem.includes(gallery: {media_items: [:media_content]}).featured.rank(:position_in_featured)
```

For this to work you need to have a type `media_content_id` and `media_content_type` columns on `MediaItem`.

EDIT: There is even a note in the docs that eager loading should work in your case in the last paragraph of this section: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Eager+loading+of+associations

Comment: Unfortunately using a Polymorphic association brings too much complexity to queries - I need to display ordered lists of MediaItems and having separate models adds a great deal of complexity. A MediaItem also carries a significant amount of data that has absolutely nothing to do with either a photo or a video and certainly not both. I prefer to keep my models focused and discrete.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the eager loading of Polymorphic associations in the docs though. It looks like that's changed recently?

Comment: Appart from using a polymorphic relationship you will not be able to do this without two queries because you need to query both models to find out if there are some records available.